# Trouble with refresh NavigatorIOS, navigationBarHidden with state

Tags: react-native

I want to control NavigatorIOS navigationBarHidden with state as below code

[image: Sample Image]

and the badge can be refresh with notifyCount from state ,
but navigationBarHidden failed

Is there something I missed?

Comment: I intend to control NavigatorIOS navigationBar hidden or not by isShowHeader from the state,
But the result is not what I expect
So give me some advises , thanks a lot

Comment: Where do you set your sate? Can you show us the code how you set it?

Comment: Please can you add your code to your post and not the image with the code.

Comment: constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      selectedTab:'home',
      notifyCount: 1,
      isShowHeader:true
    }
  }